# Is there a way to pass a row as argument to a MySQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

Roughly what I am trying to achieve:

```
CREATE FUNCTION(row Table) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
    RETURN (row.col1 > 2 OR row.col2 IS NULL)
END;
```

Comment: Hmmm, your logic only uses two columns.  Pass those as the arguments.

Comment: This is a simple example, my original goal will be more complex. It would be nice to use this in my queries and change it afterwards without code deploy. But my real concern is not writing same conditions again and again when writing a query.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.7, there will be a dynamic column, that could be added to the table itself. It's being used together with the json parsing functions added in MySQL 5.7 as well.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns